# STM32 GUI for Timers

Tags: stm32, timer, stm32f4, stm32cubemx, stm32f4-discovery

The CubeMX for STM32 MCUs gives an easy graphical interface to configure the Clock tree. I wonder if there is similar GUI tool for configuring the peripherals specially the advance timers TIMER 1 and 8?

edit:

OR is it possible that a GUI based initialization is not possible for these peripherals like Timers, Serial ports, ADCs etc? I mean that is it possible that the initializations or configurations are so convolutive that a GUI cannot handle various dependencies of some registers on other registers?

Comment: if you plan to do programming for a living , I strongly suggest you learn how to program peripherals without GUI. GUIs are not always available, are not always complete, they shield you from understanding how the logic really works which is what you often need. It takes time and effort to learn to read datasheets, so acquire the skills early.

Comment: thanks for your comments.. but i would disagree with what you have suggested.. working at baremetal level is a thing of the past now.. there are so many visual tools for everything.. i think its just not sane to do the things the old fashioned way now.. all modern tools, which are almost always gui based..  makes your efforts effective, saves you lot of time. I wonder why you gave such a bad suggestion on this forum. Obviously understanding your tool is a MUST.. and you cannot blame your tool if you use it without understanding it.. and most of the time that is fairly a common sense.

Comment: I have done a lot of ASICs design in verilog.. doing it without simulators is not possible.. but then understanding how simulators work is also very important.

Comment: @scico111 Then you haven't tried anything half-serious with CubeMX yet. It just doesn't work as promised and you will quickly get to the point where you'll begin working *against* the HAL because it is still so... 'incomplete'.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this question doesn't meet the long-term goals of this site.  Specifically, questions and answers must be long-term, not short.  Even there may not yet be GUI tools for the peripherals you are currently working with, they may become available later and render this question and all answers obsolete or outdated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the STM32CubeMX initialization generator tool provides configuration pages for the timer peripherals. Though these aren't graphical, they do allow for easier initialization of the timer resources. This includes the counter settings themselves (prescaler, direction, etc.), as well as slave configuration and settings for DMA, PWM, and other timer modes. Here's an example of the configuration page for an STM32F769's TIM1 peripheral.[image: example of TIM1 configuration page]